# How to interrupt the form posting , until pressing the confirm button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, post

There is a form like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="Delete Me">
</form>
```

I would like to change it to , when pressing the submit button, open a warning modal, If press the 'confirm' at the modal, then the form process.

Some attempt code but I wonder are there any way to 'continue' the form process after interrupt it, thanks a lot.

```
    $(function () {
        $('.delete_form').on("submit",function(){
            $('#deleteModal').modal('toggle');
            return false; //pause the submit
        });

        $('.confirm_del').on("click",function(){
            return true; //process the form submit
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code. 
Button is changed into a normal button from submit button..

```
<form action="" method="post" id="f1">
   <input type="button" id="b1" value="Delete Me">
</form>

<script>
  $('#b1').click(function(){
        $('#deleteModal').modal('toggle');
  });

  $('.confirm_del').on("click",function(){
         $("#f1").submit(); //process the form submit
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This is the way I would recommend.  It's better to allow a submit when confirmed than to cancel one when not confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
type="submit" to  type="button"
```

and then use its id or class to add an event listener then open the warning alert and submit the form on its response value.

Comment: See kuma DK's example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="theform">
<button onclick="check()">Send</button>
<script>
function check(){
//display warning
}
function ok(){
//call on ok press
document.getElementById("theform").submit();
}
</script>
```

Just don't start the submit process until the user accepts the warning...

Comment: `javascript:` URL's don't work in the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: Oops. Corrected it

Answer (score 0):

your script should like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('.delete_form').on("submit",function(){
        return confirm('Are You Sure');
    });
});
```

Comment: That would make it a modal popup (like an alert), which is not what the OP wanted. They are using their own HTML modal.

Answer (score 0):

You can also trigger the submit event of the form when confirm button is clicked.

```
     $('.confirm_del').on("click",function(){
       $('.delete_form').trigger("submit")
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
 <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return isDeleteConfirm()">
       <input type="submit" value="Delete Me">
 </form>

function isDeleteConfirm(){
        $('.delete_form').on("submit",function(){
            $('#deleteModal').modal('toggle');
            return false; //pause the submit
        });

        $('.confirm_del').on("click",function(){
            return true; //process the form submit
        });
}
```